# Direct to another page if refresh button is pressed

Tags: javascript, php

When the refresh button is pressed, I would like to send the user to a different page using PHP or javascript.
That is,

```
if (refresh pressed) header('Location: Some_Page.php');
```

Can anyone tell me how is it possible?

Comment: refresh button in your code or on the browser?

Comment: May I ask: why do you want to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to redirect the user to another page when they refresh? That will only confuse them.

Comment: Yes, when the browsers refresh button is pressed.
Because I am developing a game in which if in the middle of playing the game a player presses refresh, all logic crash. I would like to send him/her to the starting page when he/she hits the refresh button.

Comment: You could do this using sessions, fired up by every new `+1` invoked.

Comment: @Aunnoy its not good to change browser functions, even if it is possible

Comment: @Aunnoy is it a php based game?

Comment: Yes, it is php based game

Comment: you could store the game vars in a session, then the refresh button has no effect on the game?

Comment: Apparently, I am using Ajax and Javascript to change the decoration of the page after every click. So, redirecting to a new page was an easy solution to me. Now, I have to improvise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you tagged your question as `javascript`, you did also tag it as `php`

You could use [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) for this. Here is what I tried that worked.

I set the conditional statement to `10` (for testing purposes), but you can make it as `1` or any other number you wish.

**N.B.:** [`ob_start();`](http://www.php.net/ob_start) is required, otherwise it will throw an `headers already sent` error message.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
$_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;
else
$_SESSION['views']=1;
 echo "Views=". $_SESSION['views'];

if ($_SESSION['views']== 10){
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
}
?>
```

---

**Footnotes:** If you use this, `session_start();` (and maybe `ob_start();` if using `header()`) needs to be inside all files using the same session, and at the top as shown.

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't think you can hook into a specific page refresh event (I don't think it exists), you can hook into a page unload via javascript, which would be fired on a page refresh event. You would use the `onunload` or `onbeforeunload` event to trigger saving the state in cache or a cookie. (you could also on timeouts set the state every x seconds during normal gameplay)

**You cannot alert or redirect** with hooking into the `unload` or `onbeforeunload` events.

---

*the following was my original suggestion, before I tested and found you cannot do the page navigation from the `onunload` and `onbeforeunload` events*

You would also want to set a boolean saying game place has started, check for the boolean in the unload event (set that boolean to false after game is complete). That way you do not do a redirect when the user wants to actually navigate away from your game.

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(){window.location.replace(...)};
```

`window.location.href=...` would also work in the context of the `onunload` event.

Comment: you were correct, thank you for the catch, I made assumptions that were wrong. Apparently you cannot redirect (or alert) in the `onunload` or `onbeforeunload` events. changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Event click on `Refresh` button equals event of exiting current page. Use next:

```
 // jQuery
 $('body').bind('beforeunload',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var url = "http://stackoverflow.com";    
   $(location).attr('href',url); 
 });

 // JS
 window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = "http://stackoverflow.com";

    // IE8 and lower fix
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE\s(?!9.0)/)) {
       var referLink = document.createElement("a");
       referLink.href = url;
       document.body.appendChild(referLink);
       referLink.click();
     }         
     else  window.location.replace(url); 
 };
```

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to jQuery. Can you kindly tell me should I place this in the head and add a reference to jQuery (<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>) only?

Comment: @Aunnoy This code's non-jQuery equivalent isn't very complicated. It's not really worth adding a whole library for a small piece of code that can easily be vanilla JavaScript. This answer really shouldn't be using jQuery anyway, since you never tagged it.

Comment: @voodoo417 In the vanilla JS code, did you mean `window.location.href`, instead of `window.location`?

Comment: @Aunnoy use without jQuery